# How to get settings of Canon camera in auto mode?

Tags: canon, exposure, metadata, camera-settings, program-mode

I want to learn photographing in manual mode. As the one of the way I wanna shoot in auto mode and then try to repeat it in manual mode. My question is how to know which settings of ISO, shutter speed etc my camera choosen in last shot?

Camera: Canon EOS 1100D

Lens: Canon EF-S 18-55 IS II

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you take a picture in auto mode
view the picture themselef and look at the details
if the details is not shown by default, click the preview button several times until the details show up

alternatively you can Use the P mode.
It's essentially the same as auto mode but with more flexibility.

Comment: thank you! I found it with your help, 72 page in pdf manual.

Comment: To make it a little more broadly useful, some Canon cameras use the info or disp key rather than the preview key if they have one.

Answer (score 7):

1. While shooting - when you half-press the shutter button you can see the information inside the viewfinder (small numbers on the bottom of the viewfinder)
2. In camera preview - when you see the picture on the back of the camera you can view this information, press DISP to toggle showing information.
3. On the computer - in Windows right click the photo select "Properties" and switch to the "Details" tab, on a Mac right click than "Get Info". you can also see this in just about any image editor

Comment: IMO, half-pressing is the most helpful way - you can see your settings before you capture and adjust as needed. And, #3 - for a Mac, the option is right click --> "Get Info".